# Remove CSS class properties for Child List Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create an unordered List in Html.
A css class will be attached with the "ul" element and its child "li" elements.
The issue is if another "unordered List" becomes child element of this parent unordered List.

I've created following sample to show my issue:-

Javascript:-

```
$(function () {
    $('.marquee').marquee({

        duration: 10000,
        duplicate: false,
        delayBeforeStart:0,

        allowCss3Support: true,
        gap: 600,

    });
   });
```

HTML:-

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
  <ul class='marquee'>
    <li>1. Longer text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<h3>consectetur adipiscing elit END</h3></li>

    <li>2. Longer text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END</li>

    <li>3. Longer text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END</li>

    <li>4. Longer text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END</li>

        <li><ul><li><b>I'm the Child Unordered List Element. I don't want this CSS</b></li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:-

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background: black;
    color: rgb(202, 255, 195);
}
ul.marquee li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;

}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashu_mdu/s5qgt77q/)

Can any one suggest how to remove the CSS class "marquee" from the Child Unordered List?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code *within the question itself*. All you have at the moment is a broken link to a jsFiddle, so no one can help you

Comment: What CSS are you trying to remove from the child element?

Comment: For starters, that child `ul` should be inside an `li` because this is not valid html.

Comment: I just checked your Fiddle, but the child `ul` is not even getting the class `marquee`, so there's nothing to remove. I'm still not sure what it is that you want.

Comment: @vi5ion if you've notice, my child "ul" list items doesn't display with bullet points. I've updated the fiddle with what I require.

Comment: That's because of the css `ul.marquee li`. Normally that should be `ul.marquee > li` to only target the direct children, but since the JS includes a couple of `div`s inside the main `ul` that should now become `.js-marquee > li`. Or you could just target both to be safe: `ul.marquee > li, .js-marquee > li`

Comment: @vi5ion Thanks for the support. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code in your question. For now which i understood by your statement, that can be achieved by using below code (replace '.xyz' with actual class)

```
jQuery("ul.xyz").find("ul.xyz").removeClass(".xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed your `ul` within the parent `ul` is not within a `li`. Make sure any child element in a list is within a `li` element.